# ODBC connection problems

Tags: asp.net, odbc, pervasive

I'm creating an asp.net application that gathers information from a pervasive database. I'm having a hard time getting the connection to work properly though.  From my computer I am able to connect to the database and view all of the tables using the pervasive tools, however I keep getting errors when trying to access it in the application.  When I try using this code:

```
    String myConnectionString = "Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};Server=192.168.1.2;dbq=@dbname;";
```

I get an error: "ERROR [IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Pervasive ODBC Client Interface, C:\PVSW\Bin\w3odbcci.dll)."

Then when I try connecting through visual studio using the dsn I made(which works when testing the connection in ODBC Administrator) I get: "failed to call the odbc driver connection utility"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the Pervasive drivers have not been installed properly.  The Pervasive tools may work because they are all in the bin directory.

But, if there is no path to the bin directory, external modules may not be able to find and load all the DLLs required.

Comment: That worked, but now I am getting this error: "ERROR [42000] [Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Syntax Error: driver<< ??? >>={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface}" and I have no idea what it means and can't find it online, my code is the same as it was in the original comment and it is able to connect using the same string in the server explorer

Comment: What version of PSQL are you using?  Just to confirm, you are setting the ConnectionString property of an OdbcConnection object right?  The "Syntax" error usually doesn't occur until you try to execute a query.

Comment: If unsure of the connection string, here are many samples:  http://www.connectionstrings.com/pervasive